# Rust borrowing/ownership

Tags: rust, ownership, borrow-checker

I'm using tcod-rs. Each method used to draw to the `RootConsole` takes a **mutable reference**. The central loop is a `while` loop that waits for the window to close, and clears the screen, draws, and then flushes. The "check for window close" method also takes a mutable reference. `clear` and `flush` do too. I have a custom drawing function that needs a mutable reference so it can draw:

```
fn draw(root: &mut RootConsole) { /* Do state-y stuff */ }
while !root.window_closed() /* Mutable borrow 1 */ {
    root.clear(); // Mutable borrow 2
    draw(root); // Mutable borrow 3
    root.flush(); // Mutable borrow 4
}
```

The compiler has a nervous breakdown screaming about aliens stealing `RootConsole`s. I've managed to cut it down to one error by just making the changes it suggests. I can't change the tcod-rs library, or at least, I'd rather not, and I would prefer to keep using it. Replacing the `draw(root)` function with a `root.put_char(...)` for instance, works.

Here is the error I get on attempting to `cargo run`. The `tcod::console::Root` type has documentation [here](http://tomassedovic.github.io/tcod-rs/tcod/console/struct.Root.html).

```
    error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable argument `root` as mutable
  --> src/draw/mod.rs:27:33
   |
9  | pub fn draw_map(root: &mut RootConsole, world: WorldState) {
   |                 ---- consider changing this to `mut root`
...
27 |                 .draw_char(&mut root,
   |                                 ^^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

My actual draw_map code is pretty simple:

```
pub trait DrawChar {
    fn draw_char(self, root: &mut RootConsole, pos: (i32, i32));
}

pub fn draw_map(root: &mut RootConsole, world: WorldState) {
    let screen_start_y = world.screen.1;
    let screen_end_y = screen_start_y + root.height();

    let screen_start_x = world.screen.0;
    let screen_end_x = screen_start_x + root.width();

    let x = screen_start_x;
    let y = screen_start_y;
    for scan_line in &world.map[screen_start_y as usize..
                                screen_end_y as usize]
    {
        y += 1;
        for unit in &scan_line[screen_start_x as usize..
                               screen_end_x as usize]
        {
            x += 1;
            unit.tiles[world.level as usize]
                .draw_char(&mut root,
                           (x as i32 - screen_start_x,
                            y as i32 - screen_start_y));
        }
    }
}
```

Each tile implements `DrawChar`, which, since it uses functions from tcod-rs *on* a root, requires a mutable reference. My main loop isn't much different from the while loop above, except that it handles key commands using some native functions.

Comment: The call `draw(root);` should not be causing errors, because the borrow will end at the end of the statement. Could you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the errors you're getting?

Comment: I'll try to come up with one.

Comment: At least post the actual error. But ideally post code that produces that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at the `draw_char` call in `draw_map`. `root` is already a mutable reference to a `RootConsole`; you are trying to pass to `draw_char` a *mutable reference* to `root`, which essentially becomes a mutable reference to a *mutable reference* to a `RootConsole`. Simply pass `root` as the parameter and you are done.